# Fix Kerning Internal to a Unicode Character

Tags: greek, kerning, ebgaramond, diacritical-mark

Is there any way to drill down into the code that defines, for example, `Ἄ` to fix the kerning of the diacritics?  It's worse in `ebgaramond`; it's not very much better in computer modern.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{Ἄνθρωπε, οὐκ οἶδα ὃ λέγεις.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with lualatex it is better (then without \textgreek).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character in question is `Ἄ` U+1F0C GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA WITH PSILI AND OXIA and we find, in `lgrenc.dfu`,

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F0C}{\ensuregreek{\accpsilioxia\textAlpha}}        % Ἄ
```

and in `lgrenc.def` we see

```
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\accpsilioxia}{LGR}{\textAlpha}{>'A}
```

Thus the character translates directly in the combination `>'A`. In the Greek fonts, `>'` is a ligature and some fonts may provide a kerning between this character and the letter A (which is used to transliterate the Greek Alpha). For instance, if I remove the call to `ebgaramond`, the tracing by TeX shows

```
....\LGR/cmr/m/n/10 ^ (ligature >')
....\kern-0.83313
....\LGR/cmr/m/n/10 A
```

But when `ebgaramond` is used the same combination produces

```
....\LGR/EBGaramond-OsF/regular/n/10 ^ (ligature >')
....\LGR/EBGaramond-OsF/regular/n/10 A
```

No kerning. Can we add it in this case? Yes, we can.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\accpsilioxia}{LGR}{\textAlpha}{>'\kern-0.15em A}


\begin{document}

\textgreek{Ἄνθρωπε, οὐκ οἶδα ὃ λέγεις.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You'll need to fix other composite commands, I believe, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Definitely the letter of the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No need to drill down to anything. As @UlrikeFischer has already suggested in a comment, if you are willing and able to do so, by all means consider switching to either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and don't use `\textgreek` wrappers.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex  %% or 'lualatex'
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\begin{document}
Ἄνθρωπε, οὐκ οἶδα ὃ λέγεις.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Up-voted because the spirit is right, and I probably will switch to XeLaTeX.